# Android tiled image with beginning and end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'd like to do something like this:

[image]

The closest I got was with a layer list, which aligns the `left` image to the left, the `right` to the right, and sets the `center` image to repeat itself.

```
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/left"
            android:gravity="left"/>
    </item>
    <item android:left="16dp" android:right="16dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/center"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/right"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is, that the pattern doesn't know it has to repeat only "complete" iterations of `center` image, so on some screens it looks like this:

[image]

Because Android just repeats the `center` image for example 4.5 times and it doesn't properly join with the `right` one.

Is it possible to do this without implementing this functionality as a custom View, where I'd calculate and render the image?

Answer (score 1):

If the image is actually that simple as in your example. may be the best way would be to implement your own `Drawable` and paint the image in the `draw()` method.

Don't worry, this in relatively simple and probably the only way anyways to achieve what you want.